# Import mysql dump using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql dump file. How I can import this file into mysql using php?

Comment: Why not just use the command line?  mysql -u USER -p DBNAME < dump.sql

Comment: Simply break it into many SQL Statements each ending with a **;**, but keep in mind that ; should not be inside quotations

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how big the dump file is, really. A small one can just be added with a sql command. A larger one can be imported with a script.

A quick search will reveal many pre-made scripts that break down a dump into smaller chunks in order to not overload the server. I have used this one in the past: http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.php

Comment: File - 1 mb. I know about bigdump! But I need my php script which import file to mysql!

Answer (score 2):

You dump is probably a file that just contains a lot of SQL queries.

The simplest way to import such a dump is to use the [`mysql` command-line client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) *(especially if the file is big !)* :

```
mysql --user=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --host=HOST DB_NAME < /path/to/your/file.sql
```

If you can connect to your server with some command-line access *(typically, using ssh)*, that's the way to go.

Else, I suppose you could execute such a command with [**`system()`**](https://www.php.net/system)

Comment: This answer does not provide a solution for the question "Import mysql dump **using php**".

Answer (score 2):

I you want to use PHP, you can easily use the `file()` function, which reads a file into an array line by line.

You could try something like that:

```
mysql_connect(BD_HOST, DB_USER, BD_PASS) or die("Error connecting to MySQL server: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

$all_lines = file("mysql_dump.sql", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($all_lines as $query) {
    if(substr($query, 0, 2) == "--") {
        continue;
    }

    mysql_query($query) or die("Error executing query <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;"$query\"<br/>".mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use  [`multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), to import **database dump files** of medium file-size.

```
$command = file_get_contents($dumpfile);
$conn->multi_query($command);
while (mysqli_next_result($conn)); // Flush out the results.
```

**Note:** *The exact file-size limit would be dependent on your server configuration eg. `max_allowed_packet` etc.*