# How we update our local database to server database daily in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to create a PHP script to update our local database to server database, when we click a button "Upload data" from PHP script.

I searched but could not find any PHP script for that.

How can we update our data to server. I checked MySQL replication, but we want it through PHP script.

Comment: What have you tried? If you haven't tried anything than your best bet is to google it. Please google for your answer then come back and show some work of what you have tried so someone can help you.

Comment: Before you do anything, can you clarify exactly which direction the data is travelling?  Are you taking taking data From the local and sending TO the server?  Or taking data FROM the server and sending TO the local?

Comment: but what we do ?? how connect two database in one php script??

Answer (score 0):

You could dump the data from one database into a local file

e.g. using https://github.com/2createStudio/shuttle-export

and then you can import that into another database.

e.g. [Import mysql dump using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445794/import-mysql-dump-using-php)